# GOOGLE DATA STUDIO - Get the conversion percentage in a funnel

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am using Google analytics data source and my goal is to make a conversion funnel showing the percentage of users that has reached each page, using as the denominator the users of the initial page of the process.

Example:

PAGE         |      Users      |      Conversion |

page1        |           1.000 |           100% |

page2        |              800 |            80% |

page3        |              700 |            70% |

page4        |              20 |            20% |

I can get it by working the data before in a Google spreadsheet but I need to do it directly from google analytics to use the date filter.
Is it possible to achieve my objective?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not possible in GDS with the direct GA connector. Hopefully something they will update soon!